# what is wrong with the following prolog program

Tags: prolog

I made the following program, which is this:

```
eval([],_,_).
eval([(U, V)| Tail], X, Y):- 
    Y + evaluate([Tail], X, Y), Y is U * (X ** V).
```

it returns false, and I dont know why. How can I fix it?

So this `eval([(4,3), 4, X)` should return `256`.
and `eval([(4,3),(1,0)], 4, X).` should return `257`.

Now I get this error"

```
ERROR: Undefined procedure: (+)/2
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] _5562+eval([...],4,_5572)
ERROR:    [8] eval([(4,3),...],4,_5606) at c:/users/parya lotfi/desktop/exe2.pl:2
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

Comment: I doesn't **always** return `false`! Like `eval([],1,0)` succeeds!

Comment: You need to give a concrete example where you expect that it is true.

Comment: What is `Y + evaluate([Tail], X, Y)` supposed to do? In Prolog, a predicate succeeds, fails, or doesn't terminate. They don't return values like functions. That's why you're getting that ERROR. The `+` has no definition in Prolog in this context.

Comment: How can I do that then???

Comment: Please reread the error message above: You clearly see that in your program you did not use `evaluate` but rather `eval`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eval([], _,0).
eval([(U,V)|UVs], X, Y0) :-
   eval(UVs, X, Y1),
   Y0 is Y1 + U*X^V.

?- eval([(4,3),(1,0)], 4, X).
X = 257.
```